# How to affiliate boolean and numeric data to an item in a listbox C#

Tags: c#, listbox, boolean, numeric

I am creating a program that requires each item in a `listbox` to have their own data.
For example one entry could have a `checkbox` checked with a `numericUpDown` set to 20, while another would have an unchecked `checkbox` with 35 in the numericUpDown.
So far I am able to enter items to a `listbox` through a `textbox`.
I have implemented the code below, in case it is necessary.

```
private void button_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox_Movielist.Items.Add(this.text_Insert.Text);
    text_Insert.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

The program is also able to remove items from the `listbox`, so removing the boolean and numeric affiliation, just in case it remains in the saved file and gets re-affiliated when a similar data item is entered or re-entered.

```
private void button_Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox_Movielist.Items.Remove(this.listBox_Movielist.SelectedItem);
}
```

Also, would a save file with the .txt extension be suitable for something like this? If not, what would be?

Answer (score 0):

Though `ListBox` items are of type `object`, they will be displayed in the `ListBox` as strings, using the value that returns from the item `.ToString()` method.

You can create a `user control` with a `CheckBox` and `NumericUpDown`, and add it to the `ListBox.Items` collection, but don't expect to see the controls in the `ListBox`, you will only see the string representation of the user controls that is returned by the call to the `ToString()` method.

You can override the `ToString()` method to show the state of the controls inside your user control, I would suggest something along these lines:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}, {1}", 
                          MyCheckBox.CheckState.ToString(), 
                          MyNumericUpDown.Value.ToString()
                         );
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is for saving the file, so in that regard, I thank you. However, this unfortunately doesn't solve my current problem. I want each item in my `listbox` to be treated as an object of its own. So clicking on one item will check the `checkbox` while clicking another will remove the check. Same thing goes with the `numericUpDown`. One item would have it set to 20, another item to 9. Think of it as having multiple `checkboxes` and `numericUpDowns` but in a more effective and efficient way that won't bother the user.

Comment: If you need to show the controls themselves, a ListBox is not going to help you. create a user control that contains the checkbox and numeric updown, and show them on a panel. you will have to write the code for the interaction between the user controls yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can create class that stores boolean and numeric value:

```
class DataValue
{
   public bool Checked { get; set; }
   public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can declare `Dictionary<String, DataValue>`, wich stores text in your textbox as key and data as new `DataValue` object.

And if you just insert new item in your listbox, add new key in your dictionary.
If you want to get information about listbox item, get it from dictionary by key.

Comment: I've created the Class and implemented the code you  suggested. However, I am having trouble with dictionary<string, datavalue>. I can't find the correct way to put it, each time I do it, it produces an error.

Comment: Can you provide your code listing and exception you get?